# What should be included in /web/libraries/civicrm/packages?

Tags: install

This related to CiviCRM 5.60.0 running on Drupal 9.

We recently upgraded from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9, and found a problem in uploading images when editing message templates, which was traced to the `kcfinder` directory missing from `/web/libraries/civicrm/packages`.  This was replaced with the copy from the Drupal 7 site, which solved the problem.

However, while I have identified two corresponding 'package' directories in D7 and D9 ( `/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages` and `/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages` ) in D9 there is also `/web/libraries/civicrm/packages`.  I have no reference to know if there is anything else missing from the latter; is the following list correct?

[image]

With thanks, Tony

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to contain a copy of "web-accessible resources" from vendor/civicrm, meaning jpg, css, etc files.

Sometimes it gets out of sync. You can fix with `composer civicrm:publish`. Add the `-D` flag to do a complete wipe+copy.

(Ideally, instead of copies, civi would make these files available the "drupal" way, as assets declared and provided by the module, but civi is not *really* a drupal module.)

Kcfinder is known to be problematic though with civi+drupal 9 for other reasons too. You might want to give https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/summernote a try, since last I checked it had a working file browser, and had some advantages over ckeditor5 (like a view-source button). I don't know the timeline for ckeditor4, but replacing it solves the file browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have carried out "composer require ..." commands as in the live site composer.json file (into a scratch directory) and it installs the libraries shown above (at least the top-level directories), except IDS, but no others.

Unless running the install process creates some more, then it looks as if our site is now complete - though I have no idea what caused kcfinder to go missing in the first place.